# Outliers in certain values in column R

Tags: r

Outliers data

Given Data:

```
Color  |   Number
Green   |  5.0 
Red     |  20.0
Green   |  5.0    
Green   |  15.0
Green   |  100.0
Red     |  7.0
Red     |  10.0
Red     |  8.0
Green   |  6.0
```

.

Want to only take values of "green"’s number only and then plot and find outliers for them. How do you do this?

Answer (score 1):

We may `subset` the dataset where the `Color` is `"Green"`, `select` the 'Number' column and use `boxplot` and extract the `out`liers

```
boxplot(subset(Data, Color == "Green", select = Number)$Number)$out
[1] #100
```

#### data

```
Data <- structure(list(Color = c("Green", "Red", "Green", "Green", "Green", 
"Red", "Red", "Red", "Green"), Number = c(5L, 20L, 5L, 15L, 100L, 
7L, 10L, 8L, 6L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L
))
```

Comment: It says "Error in x[floor(d)] + x[ceiling(d)] : 
non-numeric argument to binary operator'

Comment: @CodeGirl1234 that may be because your `Number` column is not numeric.  I assumed it is numeric

Answer (score 0):

Get the values for the `Green` color:

`GreenValues = Data[Data$Color=='Green',]`

Then use `boxplot.stats` to get the outliers:

`boxplot.stats(GreenValues$Number)$out`

Hope it helps.

Comment: It's giving Error in x[floor(d)] + x[ceiling(d)] : 
non-numeric argument to binary operator

Comment: Try `boxplot.stats(as.numeric(GreenValues$Number))$out`

Comment: Or show me how your data looks like and the code you wrote. Show me the output of `str(Data)`.